# How to draw Hindi text on Webview in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new in android so please help me. my question is 
I want to draw hindi text on `WebView` in android, I am using following code

```
<string name="hindi_content">विज्ञान के इस युग में मानव को जहां कुछ वरदान मिले है </string>
```

```
    WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String s = getResources().getString(R.string.hindi_content);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.loadData(s, "text/html", null);
    }
```

but it displaying the special characters. so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to load हिन्दी:

```
wv.loadData(s, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of a bug with the encoding parameter of loadData in most Android versions. This parameter is ignored for some reason so the UTF-8 based hindi characters will not be rendered. To fix this you can use one of the following alternatives.

```
webview1.loadData(hindi_content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);


webview1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, hindi_content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```